# Power Automate Desktop - Create library of subflows or stored functions

Tags: power-automate

Still coming up to speed on Power Automate Desktop - I'd like to create a utility library with functions that can be called from different flows in Power Automate Desktop.

Maybe starting with something simple, like creating my own HashSet with a function like:  addIfMissing(myHashSetList, "abc")

Any hints or advice?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this yourself, Dan?  I'm in the same situation as you.

Comment: Sepster - No, we never did.  We've since moved away from Power Automate, so we've not dedicated any effort there.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Dan. We're currently exploring a selenium/appium/WinAppDriver based solution from within .Net.